# CSS image wrap issue - depends on browser zoom level

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create a panel of 5 images across a DIV where a jQuery `animate()` expands each image in succession until all 5 images consume 100% of the width of their container **without wrapping**

[Here](https://www.avantalytics.com/) is the link to the problem:

The initial blockUI displays fine, but once its expires and the normal page is shown, the same five images will display perfectly under some resolutions (I use ctrl-+/- in either FF or IE to test) and others it causes the last image to wrap.

The code to animate the resizing is below, and its purpose is to resize each image up to 20% of the width of the container. I've tried to see if it had to do with rounding and have come up empty. I've looked into CSS options trying some/all of the following:

```
overflow:hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
display:inline-block;


$(".service_img").each(function (i) 
  {
    // if the image in question's width is > 20% of its container then re-adjust it to be 20% so it will fit
    if($('#'+this.id).outerWidth() > Math.floor((($('#services_imgs_container').outerWidth()/5)))){
      $('#'+this.id).width(Math.floor(($('#services_imgs_container').outerWidth()/5)));
    }
    else {
      $('#'+this.id).animate({width:(Math.floor(($('#services_imgs_container').outerWidth()/5)))},{duration:500, queue:false});
      //$('#'+this.id).animate({width:'19.2%'},{duration:500, queue:false});
      $('#'+this.id).show();
    }

  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function after the resize, and check to see if #services_imgs_container is twice the height of div.service_img:eq(0).  If it is reduce the size of each .service_img by one pixel at a time until the statement is no longer true.

something like this

```
while($('#services_imgs_container').height() >= ($('.service_img:eq(0)').height() * 1.5))
{
    $('.service_img').css('width': '-=1');
}
```

Comment: the width is the problem, but your suggestion remains in force - let me try it and see how it goes.  thx.

Comment: right, the reason I'm checking for height, is that if the height of the containter is twice the height of the children, then we know it's displaying the children in 2 lines, not one.  So if it's on 2 lines I reduce the of each element until it jumps back to one line, in which case the height of the container would also change.

Comment: Ok, this worked, but with the following behavior - even when doing this in a promise.done() after the animate() sometimes the height returned 350 for both and sometimes 700 for the container which would cause this while loop to occur.  There seems to be an issue with the while statement executing sometimes before the parent container expands and it evals to false, then the container expands due to the wrap and the problem remains.

Comment: Also - the .css should utilize a comma not a colon in the above (small change).

Comment: Does anyone have a handle on how to ensure we always wait for the container to expand (if its going to do so) before we evaluate the while loop test above?  Right now I'm hacking it by moving the while loop after a couple more statements in the .done() portion to allow time for the container to expand, but this is not optimal for obvious reasons as their still is no guarantee on timing.